# Push to Git using Rugged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I worked in a script to push to git using a script, so I choose Rugged to do that, my probleme when I try to push to repo, it gives me error, Can you help me ?

```
require 'rugged'


git_email = 'ettaheri.nizar@gmail.com'
git_name = 'Nizar'
repo_name = '/Users/euphor/Desktop/test/testignore1'


repo = Rugged::Repository.new('/Users/euphor/Desktop/test/testignore1')
puts "1"
index = repo.index
puts "3"

oid = repo.write("This is a blob.", :blob)

index.add(:path => "testignore1", :oid => oid, :mode => 0100644)
puts "4"

options = {}
options[:tree] = index.write_tree(repo)
puts "5"
options[:author] = { :email => git_email, :name => git_name, :time => Time.now }
options[:committer] = { :email => git_email, :name => 'Test Author', :time => Time.now }
puts "6"
options[:message] ||= "Making a commit via Rugged!"
options[:parents] = repo.empty? ? [] : [ repo.head.target ].compact
options[:update_ref] = 'HEAD'
puts "7"
Rugged::Commit.create(repo, options)
puts "8"
**repo.push 'origin'**  # this is my error
puts "Done"
```

the message of my error is :

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.23.0/lib/rugged/repository.rb:224:in
>   `push': Unsupported URL protocol (Rugged::NetworkError)  from
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.23.0/lib/rugged/repository.rb:224:in`
>   push'  from vips.rb:43:in `'

Comment: Please run `git remote show origin` inside of your repository and show output.

Comment: this is the output : remote origin
 Fetch URL: git@devserver:nizar/testignore1
 Push URL : git@devserver:nizar/testignore1
head branch : master
remote branch : master tracked

Comment: This is strange. What is your operating system? Ubuntu?

Comment: not Ubuntu, I use OSX

Comment: What's your packet manager, Homebrew?

Comment: I don't know, where I can found it ?

Comment: I will add an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have libgit2 (backend for Rugged) not installed properly. Most convenient packaging solution for Mac OS if Homebrew, and you need it to install additional libraries.

**Install Homebrew**

Follow any on-screen instructions after executing this line:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Install openssh**

```
brew install openssh
```

**Reinstall rugged gem**

```
gem uninstall rugged
gem install rugged
```

Now your snippet should run fine.